# android - measure radiation from device

Tags: android, networking, hardware, sensors, android-sensors

I was wondering if there is an option to measure the radiation coming from the device.

Just to clarify, I am talking about cell phone radiation, that is coming when making a call, and is very **high** if you would make a call in an elevator, for example.

I also have two more questions, sort of related:

1. Is there a way to check how strong the mobile network signal is? or detect when its getting weak?
2. Is there away to check "how much" transmission the phone "did" in the last minute, for example? I mean, if I just made a few calls, the "transmission" would be high.

any ideas?

Comment: "I was wondering if there is an option to measure the radiation coming from the device" -- no.

Comment: "_Is there a way to check how strong the mobile network signal is? or detect when its getting weak?_", You _can_ do that though, using Android's APIs, not sure which exactly though. Unfortuately, the other things you mentioned are not possible, unless you get an external device which measures radiation (Which _does_ exist). You can't do it from the phone, though, although you could monitor incoming / outgoing call lengths, and "guess" from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find mobile network signal using onSignalStrengthsChanged method of PhoneStateListener